# Magento2 how to insert link inside the img tag with knockout js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

```
<img data-bind="attr:{src: 'pub/media/catalog/product'+image_url}"/>
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: name" class="product-item-link">
                </a>
```

**Can somebody help me with this? I wanted to make the image clickable but whenever I try to put it inside the  tag, the image doesn't show**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not valid HTML, the `img` needs to be inside the `a`.

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: name" class="product-item-link">
    <img data-bind="attr:{src: 'pub/media/catalog/product'+image_url}"/>
</a>
```

Comment: I wanted to make the image clickable to it's product url

Comment: Yes, to do that you need to write valid HTML. Your link doesn't contain anything at all, you need to add the image to your link.

Comment: The link contains the url of the product. The image doesn't show whenever I put it inside <a> tag.

Comment: You'll have to debug why, maybe it's a CSS issue? So the image does display when it's outside the A tag?

Comment: I created a new <a> tag which only contains the product_url and it worked. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Sounds like the class `product-item-link` was the cause

Comment: I actually found a solution here on my own. I tried to recreate the <a> tag with only the product_url in it and did not include the "html: name". Thanks anyways for the help.

Answer (score 0):

u should try this example:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="popup" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/','popup','width=1000,height=800'); return false;"><img class="img-bank pull-left" data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('images/path') }" title="Google" style="width:auto;height:28px;"></a>
```